# Log4j2 on Tomcat on Windows produces warning "unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream"

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, tomcat, log4j2

I have a web app deployed on Tomcat 8.  My dev env is Eclipse (Luna) on Windows 7 x64.
I just finished integrating log4j2 in my code.
When I start up Tomcat, I see the following warning:

```
WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
```

I did extensive googling but could not see any question related to my problem. I did see that the class is supposed to add coloring to the log file. I am not interested in this feature.

The log4j config is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="TRACE">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, After diggind into the log4j2 code, I found a hidden runtime parameter that needs to be specified:

```
-Dlog4j.skipJansi=true
```

Comment: I have somehow the same problem, but I'm using Scala, and getting Unrecognized option: -dlog4j.skipjansi=true any idea?

Comment: the option is case sensitive.

Comment: This can also be done with `System.setProperty("log4j.skipJansi", "true")`